# How to properly secure my Wordpress installation?

Tags: plugins, security, server, installation

I'm currently on my own server (fredericpilon.com) with my own website.

Wordpress being kind of a big shot of CMS, it may be targeted by hacks.

Any tips and tricks on how to properly secure my Wordpress installation from said hackers and evil-doers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress
- http://perishablepress.com/press/tag/security/ (lots of great
  articles)
- http://www.wpsecure.net/secure-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your business needs. If you're running it for a personal blog or a small site then stay away from suspicious plugins and hosting providers and you'll be fine. There are some good security/backup plugins which tend to sometimes work. The best advice though is "stay updated" ;)

If you're doing something bigger then go for [VaultPress](http://vaultpress.com/) (not free). If you're doing a large-scale project go for [WordPress.com VIP](http://vip.wordpress.com/) (not free at all!)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: For sure, being a personal site, nothing big, something free would more suit the need. But thanks, these two could come handy some day.

Answer (score 1):

I think this article will be spot on. Just found it tody :)

http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/10/securing-your-wordpress-website/

Here are some more links on the subject:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-steps-to-securing-your-wordpress-installation/

Comment: These all seem good ways to go. And by Smashing, it's pretty safe to say they know what they are talking about.

Comment: It's actually pretty horrible.

Answer (score 1):

So many things you need to look at and they are not just to do with WordPress.

Here is a video that I like about WordPress security as it mentions on of my plugins: http://wordpress.tv/2011/11/07/damian-taggart-wordpress-security-the-end-of-innocence/

Also there is a good book about WordPress security I recommend that I have read also:
[http://www.amazon.co.uk/WordPress-Ultimate-Security-Olly-Connelly/dp/1849512108](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849512108)